# How to completly wipe hard drive and reinstall windows 7 from back-up dvd.

Tags: windows-7

How do I completly erase hard drive? How do I reinstall windows 7 from orininal back-up DVD and will that reboot the system? I changed the windows 7 default browser to 64-bit in a praogram window trying to solve these issues and do not remmber how I did it. Could you explain that to me? So I can change after the reinstall becouse it will go back to the 32-bit defoult and I want the 64-bit ie8. I have windows 7 Home Premium os and ie8 with google as my search engine. My laptop is a Toshiba Satellite P770-ST4N01

Comment: Page 76 of the User Manual has instructions how to [Restoring from recovery DVD/Media](http://www.manualowl.com/m/Toshiba/Satellite-P770-ST4N01/Manual/282378?page=76).

Comment: Why don't you just describe the problem you are trying to solve by reinstalling Windows 7 instead?

Answer (score 1):

Just boot your computer with the DVD inserted.

This will show you a "Press any key to boot from cd or dvd" message: just press any key; this will start the windows installation.

When asked, choose "Custom installation", delete all partitions and recreate them.